# Why do a lot of logging frameworks provide individual methods instead of a enum 'level'?

Tags: logging

I see some of the more preferred logging frameworks like log4j, log4net etc all use 'trace, debug' etc methods.

Why do they use these instead of methods that take something like a enum level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Log4j, at least, has both. The methods with just the log level name such as `logger.debug(...)` are convenience methods that simply call `logger.log(DEBUG, ...)`. You can read more about this at the [Custom Log Levels](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customloglevels.html) documentation page:

> ### Convenience Methods for the Built-in Log Levels
>
> The built-in log levels have a set of convenience methods on the Logger interface that makes them easier to use. For example, the Logger interface has fourteen `debug()` methods that support the DEBUG level:
>
> ```
> // convenience methods for the built-in DEBUG level
> debug(Marker, Message)
> debug(Marker, Message, Throwable)
> ...
> ```